# How to open a link on a secondary monitor using HTML5?

Tags: html, browser, webkit

Is it possible to open a link in a new browser window on a secondary monitor connected to my PC using HTML5?

Comment: You cannot using only html5/javascript send output to another screen, HOPEFULLY!

Comment: What else do I need to use?

Comment: Client side application in C++/csharp/java or anything else that can access to OS fonctionalities

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to check if user are using multiple monitors but You may check the width of the user screen comparing to height. If it is bigger than 1.9 you can assume that he have two monitors. Then you could try to open second window with big left offset and there will be a chance that it will jump to second monitor.

i.e in case of two 1024x768 monitors the width is 2048. If you will open window on for example 1280 from left it should be on second screen. Of course user can have monitors of diffrent resolution so it may not work in every case.

And you can also check the width and position of the browser as it may help to identify where current monitor ends.

That's just the idea ofcourse, I never tested it.